# joomla: why does Registration Form menu item go to user's Profile page?

Tags: joomla, registration, menuitem

I created a new menu item: **my_RegistrationForm_menu_item** (type = *Registration Form*).

But when I click my_RegistrationForm_menu_item, it goes to "User Profile" page instead of the "Registration Form" page.

Also, if I append: `index.php/component/users/?view=registration`

OR `index.php?option=com_users&view=registration`

to my browser URL, it re-directs me to `index.php/.../profile`

NOTE: if I click the Create An Account button in the default LOGIN module, it will correctly take me to the "Registration Form" page.

Why does the *Registration Form* menu item go to the user's "User Profile" page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have selected **type = Registration**, then there is no reason why it should be redirecting to the User Profile page, unless you have touched any related core Joomla files.

As an alternative, you can select **type = External** and use the following link:

```
index.php?option=com_users&view=registration
```

**Update:**

You can also do the following:

1. Create a new menu (not menu item) called "**hidden**"
2. Create a new menu item for the "hidden" menu called "**register**", set the type to "**external**" and add the link that I provided above.
3. Create a new menu item for your main menu, set the type to "**Menu Item Alias**" and called it "**Register**". Then in the Required Setting section, select the hidden menu item you created before.

If this still dosn't work then there is something wrong with your Joomla site and the `com_users` code has been tampered with most likely

Comment: that could work ... I'll still hold my breath in hopes that I can get the type = Registration Form to work correctly. thanks.

Comment: Lodder, when I append your link to my url in the browser address bar, it re-directs me to 'index.php/.../profile' ... I would have expected it to work.

Comment: still no go ... I have also gone to one of my other joomla sites and created a Registration Form menu item, and it also goes to the profile.

Comment: I am an idiot ... my goal is to let the administrator register new members from the front end ... so I was logged in the whole time as administrator. Once I logged out it was fine. Therefore your answer is right.

Comment: I do wish I could have the behavior of a blank reg. form when logged in as admin (I do not want my client to access the back end)

Comment: if you don't want your client to access the backend, then you can install the [JLSecure My Site](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/backend-a-full-access-control/18288), plugin, which adds a key and value requirement to the admin URL ;)